# multi shell_exec to one shell_exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

Is there a method to short this commands in one shell_exec?

```
shell_exec("$ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathOGG"); 

shell_exec("$ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathMP4"); 

shell_exec("$ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathWEBM");
```

something like this:

```
shell_exec("$ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathWEBM,$outPathMP4,$outPathWEBM");
```

Also Is it better to use shell_exec or exec for this job?

Comment: you put all your scripts into 1 bash file and execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
shell_exec("$ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathOGG & $ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathMP4 & $ffmpegPath  -i $inputPath -i $watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 $outPathWEBM");
```

This just combines the shell_execs with an & sign in between commands. It should work.